# How to return data in alphabetical order from 2 different shards?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server what is the correct way to retrieve data that is in alphabetical order from the same table on 2 different shards?

Right now on the db I am working on there is a table that exists on 2 different shards. I need to be able to select the data from each table in alphabetical order in batches of 5. So for example.

In Shard1 we have a table with 6 items of data

```
A,
A,
A,
A,
A,
A
```

In Shard2 we have a table with 4 items of data

```
A2,
B2,
C2,
D2,
```

When I run my query the first time I need to return

```
A,
A,
A,
A,
A
```

When I run it the next time it should return

```
A,
A2,
B2,
C2,
D2
```

I have been looking through documentation but unclear what to do. The reason is that this seems not possible because there would have to be some sort of middle component that would have to keep track of the alphabetical order of each table in separate databases. I know it is easy to execute operations that alphabetize on 1 table in 1 database, but across databases and tables seems not possible. What is the correct way to do this with sql server? Or this even possible?

Comment: I don't know what a "shard" is, but the general approach is "get top(n) from each thing, union them all to create one cohesive set, then get the top(n) from *that*".

Comment: In order to implement backend pagination the rows needs to have a unique identifier that clearly identifies each row. This doesn't seem to be your case since all six rows in the first "shard" cannot be distinguished.

Comment: @TheImpaler for the sake of simplicity i omitted some columns. The question is more about how to get 2 tables which are the same but of different shards to be alphabetized together. I can now paginate through each one of them separately in their alphabetical order. They are alphabetized each according to what what exists in their respective table, but if I take the top 50 rows of each table while being alphabetized aloned in their respective tables, they combination of the tables will be not alphabetized.

Comment: Apparently database "sharding" is a thing that I too have never heard of. The concept is familiar but from the explanation it seems I would never use it in practice as it is meant for scale-out databases far beyond the size I would ever work with. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-database-sharding

Comment: @TimJarosz Sharding is a common concept in the general database space. But it is not a feature that exists in Microsoft SQL Server, so it's still unclear what OP is talking about in this context.

Comment: I suspect the OP has an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not fully clear what you're asking about since sharding isn't a concrete feature in SQL Server.

That being said, let's assume you have two separate SQL Server instances, with the same table, and you've setup a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) between them. You can combine the two sets of data with a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` (depending on if you want to remove or keep duplicates in the dataset, respectively) within a subquery and then order them alphabetically like so:

```
SELECT TOP 5 -- Top 5 alphabetically 
    ItemId
FROM
(
    SELECT ItemId
    FROM dbo.Items -- Local instance's copy of the table

    UNION -- Removing duplicates (as per your example)

    SELECT ItemId
    FROM LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.Items -- Remote instance's copy of the table
) AS Items
ORDER BY ItemId
```

Comment: Ok cool. Im reading about linked servers but it's still not clear to me. Is this going to be able to s select from the tables alphabetically even though they are not in the same table and the data between the tables is different? For example, I need to be able to get the next 5 entries in alphabetical order across 2 different tables. It needs to return a result from 2 tables in alphabetical order as if it is coming from 1 table.

Comment: @Dan Yep, that's what the example code is doing and the point of using the `UNION` or `UNION ALL` keyword. If you want only a certain number of results, then just add a `TOP 5` or whatever number you want, after the `SELECT` on the very first line of the query.